# Can't seem to figure out what Facebook wants from me in regards of a redirect?

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth

[image: I have already turned on both WebOAuth and ClientOauth.]
This seems to be something new that Facebook has recently updated over the past few months and I want the redirect to simply take users to the home page. I've already added https://  to all my redirects, so I think its some type of format error.
[image]
`https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?client_id{{facebook_id}}&state=dd3925d67cf58016de9aa8874caf3135&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.6.2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fhousesforsaleinmd.com%2Fmy-profile%2F&scope=email&ret=login&fbapp_pres=0&logger_id=ea17a674-1368-4015-afc3-3df73e4471ee&cbt=1586993724578&ext=1586996749&hash=AeZ0mz9F9GDwRi4S`

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: Jokingly, I'd also add that I sense a question is somewhere in this post but I could not find it :)

Comment: Wrote the question too quickly, been fighting with this problem all week. Can't seem to figure out what Facebook wants from me in regards of a redirect. All documentation I've came across was 3-4 years old.

Comment: [Edit] your post and add your question there.  From the screenshot, however, it seems that in your App's Client Oath settings, you need to include the URL that you are redirecting to (but you have not done so yet) - check your app's settings to verify this

Comment: I've added the urls to the Facebook client OAuth settings in the Valid OAuth section.

Comment: The redirect_uri is `https://housesforsaleinmd.com/my-profile/`. I can't see that in your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Comment: You are redirecting to `https://housesforsaleinmd.com/my-profile/` which is not whitelisted (just like the error message says)

Comment: Okay thank you that seemed to work

Comment: feel free to delete this question as it really does not meet the community guidelines and it applies only to you :)